# How accurately do we need to know an approximation of $\pi$ to compute $\sqrt{\pi}$ with four correct decimal?

Tags: error-propagation

An approximation $\overline{x}$ of $x$ is said to have $t$ correct decimals if and only if $|\overline{x}-x| \leq \frac{1}{2} 10^{-t}$.

Suppose that $\overline{x} = x \pm \frac{1}{2} 10^{-k}$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then:
$$\vartriangle f = f(\overline{x})-f(x) \approx f'(x) e_a(\overline{x},x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{2} 10^{-k}$$.

I don't know whether am I messing things up or not, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note $\sqrt{3.141579}\approx 1.772449999294$ which rounds to $1.7724$ while $\sqrt{\pi} \approx 1.772453850906$ which rounds to $1.7725$ so although the error in the square root is about $0.0000038516\approx \frac{\pi -3.141579}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$, the rounded fourth decimal place is different.

Comment: I would write the computations in this way.  Let $r(x):=\sqrt{x}$ ; then 
$\dfrac{\Delta r}{\Delta x} \approx \dfrac{dr}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \implies \Delta r = \dfrac{\Delta x}{2\sqrt{x}} $ meaning that the error is divided by $\approx 3.5$...